# Highlight current month name in conditional formatting

Tags: excel, date, conditional-formatting

I have month's name from `January` to `December` in C12:C23. They do not have dates tied to them, just month names.

What is the conditional formatting formula I can use to highlight the current month?

Do I format them as something specific too?

Answer (score -1):

In case rows may be added or deleted above C12, please clear any CF from C12:C23 select that range and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=TEXT(TODAY(),"mmmm")=C12
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select highlighting of choice, <kbd>OK</kbd>, <kbd>OK</kbd>.